# Tableview cell shadow does not render properly Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, shadow, dropshadow

I have been able to add shadows to the bottom of my tableview cells using the following code, however it seems to disappear after 
I scroll down.

```
cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,2)
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 3
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
let shadowFrame: CGRect = cell.layer.bounds
let shadowPath: CGPathRef = UIBezierPath(rect: shadowFrame).CGPath
cell.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath
cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42nFR.png)

Comment: Where do you place this code? In a subclass of UITableViewCell or in the cellForRowAtIndexPath or in willDisplayCell?

Answer (score 3):

The issue was to do with the shadow offset, which I've managed to rectify with the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.bounds).CGPath
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false

}
```